Multiple indices in NumPy
The following works:
np.array([[10,20,30,40]])[:,[1,3,2]]

How can I do this kind of slicing for a one-dimensional array? In other words, how can I fix the following to make the indices refer to the same dimension instead of three different dimensions?
np.array([10,20,30,40])[1,3,2]


np.array([10,20,30,40])[1,3,2] is the same as np.array([10,20,30,40])[(1,3,2)], a tuple of indices, one for each dimension. In indexing the distinction between lists and tuples is important.

If I understood correctly, just wrap the indices in a list:
np.array([10,20,30,40])[[1,3,2]]
# array([20, 40, 30])


I wonder why they did not introduce this kind of indexing in Python itself.
